# Printing Opcodes to a File

Tags: opcodes

Just curious, if open a hex editor and type opcodes manually and save it. Such as move 1 to register 1 move 2 to register 2 then call add, would that give me working program? Or does some how automating this  gives me crappy compiler?

EDIT: Forgot about OS, I have Mac OS X and Linux at my disposal, x86's as the CPU.

Comment: A platform/OS would be useful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, the OS/platform is important here. Most platforms will expect some sort of structure to an executable (if only a header etc.). e.g. see [the a.out format](http://fuse4bsd.creo.hu/localcgi/man-cgi.cgi?a.out+5) as used by older versions of Unix.

As you've indicated you have Mac OS X, check out the [Mach-O format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O).

Beware that typing `'A0 A1'...` etc. is different from putting the *actual bytes* (in this case 160/161) in the file.

Comment: i am thinking of writing a script to do the writing or do it with a hex editor. But does it need to be structured? or would it still work?

Comment: The OS will expect some sort of format

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the proper file format for the binary then yes.

Old DOS .com files were just this - the raw program serialized out to disk.  .exe files and unix ELF files have a structured format to them which includes (among other things) relocation information.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the file is a properly formatted executable binary file. See references on the COFF and ELF formats, for example.

You could also dump the contents of a small executable file using `od` if you're curious about what a particular executable file looks like.